# Making an ajax get request with django

Tags: python, ajax, django, jquery-get

Trying to simply make an ajax call to my view and get the template html back.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        data:{language:'English'},
        dataType:'html',
        success:function (data, status, xhr) {
            alert('works yea');
            $('#profiles-section').html(data);
        }
       error: function(data){
            alert('errors');
        }
    });
});
```

My test view which I have verified has the correct url is never called, I have set break points and nothing happens, I am alerting the url on the client side before I make the ajax call and it should match what I have defined in my urls.py.

```
def teset_view(request, username):
   template = 'profiles_view.html'
   return render_to_response(template,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Have I missed something simple?

UPDATE:

I added the error to see if it would error and I receive this alert, how can I figure out why jquery errors like this. I don't have any other conflicting places where I would cross reference

It looks like I am running into a jqXHR status always returning zero

```
error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            }
```

What can I do to fix this, I have tried adding a `e.preventDefault` at the end of the on click method

UPDATE

My url is set up this way

```
url(r'^profiles/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$','Taleebo.views.profiles_view',name="profiles"),
```

, i have added the getCookie() javascript safe method so i can make proper ajax request.

Comment: did you try adding the `type: "GET"` parameter to your $.ajax function?

Comment: yes i did. I have updated my question. to show that it alerts on error, with no help from jquery on why

Comment: try console.log(data) in your error handler function

Comment: I don't think django lets you make requests unless you add the csrf token in the request parameters. Get the `csrftoken` cookie following this method and request with it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: run the site in the dev server and watch the terminal output, what does it say when you send the ajax request?

Comment: @Bibhas I'm pretty sure you only need the csrf token for POST. Well I have a django project with AJAX and all the AJAX requests are GET and I never need the token.

Comment: Could you update your question with url (from ajax call) and url sytax from urls.py?

Comment: @Warz do you have [this](https://gist.github.com/miki725/3892061) added in your JS?

Comment: @Jonathan i will add this and post my results.

Comment: I have added this now with no update, i still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable. Found out that my link was canceling the ajax request.

Simply adding `return false` after the on click method fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors. Install **firebug** and you will see where they are!